# MVC Passing models vs viewmodels - how to retain model meta-information?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, attributes, automapper

I want to define "Description" attributes on my models, for general use with tooltips, grids, reports, etc, plus Validation & other attributes:

```
 public class MyModel
 {
     ...
     [DisplayName("Yo thang")]
     [Description("This field determines the XYZ blah-de-blah")] // Tooltips
     [StringLength(100)] // Validation
     public string CoolThing { get; set; }
     ...
 }
```

In the Detail/Edit views for MyModel, I want "This field determines..." to be automatically wired up as a tooltip, and validation to kick in.

I have this currently functioning when the view is given MyModel directly (helper function reads the attribute & wires up jquery widget).

However, I'm considering moving to ViewModels+AutoMapper, and clearly I will lose this functionality as the attribute isn't on the viewmodel:

```
 public class MyViewModel
 {
     ...
     public string CoolThing { get; set; }
     ...
 }
```

I don't want to put the attribute on MyViewModel, since many ViewModels will have this property and this would duplicate the information (non-DRY).

What's my best option for preserving the meta information in a single location, but retaining the benefits of ViewModels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MohammadRB & others,

After some playing around I have a solution I'm satisfied with.

Using [MetadataType(typeof(MyModel))] on MyViewModel doesn't work, as it requires MyViewModel implement all the properties of MyModel (which defeats half the point).

Instead I have taken this path:

1) Create a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider as described here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/06/14/asp.net-mvc-localization-displaynameattribute-alternatives-a-better-way.aspx

2) Create a custom ModelMetadata attribute (same syntax as MetadataType)

3) In my custom metadata provider, I check if the containerType has [ModelMetadata] defined. If so, I look up the property (if it exists), load the custom attributes, and Concat them to the attributes enumerable.

The source code in full:

```
public sealed class ModelMetaTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ModelMetaTypeAttribute(Type modelType)
    {
        ModelType = modelType;
    }

    public Type ModelType { get; private set; }
}

public static class ModelMetaTypeUtilities
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<PropertyInfo, ICollection<Attribute>> MetaAttributesCache = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, ICollection<Attribute>>();

    public static ICollection<Attribute> GetMetaAttributes(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        // Lookup from cache if possible
        var key = propertyInfo;
        if (MetaAttributesCache.ContainsKey(key)) return MetaAttributesCache[key];

        //Try the metadataType instead as well
        ICollection<Attribute> attributes = new List<Attribute>();
        var classType = propertyInfo.DeclaringType ?? propertyInfo.ReflectedType;
        var metadataTypeAttribute = classType.GetCustomAttribute<ModelMetaTypeAttribute>();
        if (metadataTypeAttribute != null)
        {
            var metadataType = metadataTypeAttribute.ModelType;

            var metadataPropertyInfo = metadataType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);
            if (metadataPropertyInfo != null)
            {
                attributes = metadataPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes().ToList();
            }
        }

        MetaAttributesCache.Add(key, attributes);
        return attributes;
    }
}

// For more info see: http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/06/14/asp.net-mvc-localization-displaynameattribute-alternatives-a-better-way.aspx
public class CustomDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
        Type containerType,
        Func<object> modelAccessor,
        Type modelType,
        string propertyName)
    {

        var allAttributes = IncludeMetaAttributes(containerType, propertyName, attributes);

        var meta = base.CreateMetadata(allAttributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        return meta;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Attribute> IncludeMetaAttributes(Type containerType, string propertyName, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        var propertyInfo = !propertyName.IsNullOrEmpty() ? containerType.GetProperty(propertyName) : null;
        if (propertyInfo == null) return attributes;

        var metaAttributes = propertyInfo.GetMetaAttributes();
        return attributes.Concat(metaAttributes);
    }
}
```

And in Application_Start:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your attrs in a partial class:

```
public partial ModelMetaData
{
    [Description("This field determines the XYZ blah-de-blah")] // Tooltips
    [StringLength(100)] // Validation
    public string CoolThing { get; set; }
}
```

and in declare your model and view model with `MetadataType` attr and as partial:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ModelMetaData))]
public partial class Model
{
    public string CoolThing { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ModelMetaData))]
public partial class MyViewModel
{
    public string CoolThing { get; set; }
}
```

This buddy classes must be defined in same NameSpace.

(I have never use this approach before, but i think it will do what you want)

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, this is certainly an option, although for ease of development & simplicity for other developers it would obviously be cleaner to keep the meta information directly on the model itself. Come to think of it... could MyViewModel have [MetadataType(typeof(MyModel))] ?

Comment: @BrendanHill Yes putting meta information on model class will be cleaner but in your situation i prefer this approach(because i don't know another approach :) what is the problem with `[MetadataType(typeof(ModelMetaDate))]` on `MyViewModel`?

Comment: If it's possible to use the MetadataType of the model itself, then I can a) keep my attributes on my model (the preferred place); and b) write just model+viewmodel instead of model+viewmodel+metamodel - keeping it simple.

Comment: @BrendanHill At first glance, i don't understand what you said. Yes that is a good idea. Does that work?